# Missing "soap:fault" element exception while making wsdl file to java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

Her i have //path/a/wsdl file and i amtrying to generate webservices client program , but when we added the file ,it is showing the below error

**sample wsdl :**
wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://xyz.com/"
    xmlns:tns="http://xyz.com/" xmlns:cmn="http://xyz.com/Common/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">

```
        <s:element name="GetPublisherRevenueCSV">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="name" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="pwd" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="operatorId" type="s:int" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="criteria" type="tns:PublisherRevenueCriteria" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>

        <s:element name="GetPublisherRevenueCSVResponse">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" name="CSVFile" type="tns:CSVFile" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>

        <s:complexType name="CSVFile">
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="File" type="s:hexBinary"
                    xmime:expectedContentTypes="text/plain" />
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>


        <s:complexType name="PublisherRevenueCriteria">
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="publisherId" type="s:int" />
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="adSpaceId" type="s:int" />
                <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="startDate" type="s:date" />
                <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="endDate" type="s:date" />                  
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>


    </s:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="GetPublisherRevenueCSVSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPublisherRevenueCSV" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="GetPublisherRevenueCSVSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPublisherRevenueCSVResponse" />
</wsdl:message>
```

```
    <wsdl:operation name="GetPublisherRevenueCSV">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:GetPublisherRevenueCSVSoapIn" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:GetPublisherRevenueCSVSoapOut" />
        <wsdl:fault name="CMS_API_Exception" message="cmn:CMS_API_Exception" />
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="PublisherRevenueWSSoap" type="tns:PublisherRevenueWSSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

    <wsdl:operation name="GetPublisherRevenueCSV">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://xyz.com/GetPublisherRevenueCSV"
            style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="CMS_API_Exception">
            <soap:fault name="CMS_API_Exception" use="literal" />
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

**ERROR:**
 IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing  element inFault "CMS_API_Exception" in operation "CMS_API_Exception", in binding GetPublisherRevenueCSV
        java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing  element inFault "CMS_API_Exception" in operation "CMS_API_Exception", in binding GetPublisherRevenueCSV
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.faultsFromSOAPFault(SymbolTable.java:2858)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populateBindings(SymbolTable.java:2549)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:744)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.add(SymbolTable.java:543)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:518)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
        at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: can any help me to solve this..

Comment: all I see is a stack trace. with what code are you having problems with, what are you doing, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead? what is your source data? please add the information to the question...

Comment: please share the code and explain what is the problem the n give stack trace just stack trace wont help.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue,,,
 change from

It schould work.

```
 <wsdl:fault name="CMS_API_Exception">
        <soap:fault name="CMS_API_Exception" use="literal" />
```

to

```
    <soap:fault name="CMS_API_Exception">
        <soap:fault name="CMS_API_Exception" use="literal" />
    </soap:fault>
```